# Dynamically injecting script tag while using Webpack

Tags: webpack, facebook-javascript-sdk

I used to inject Facebook SDK exactly the way that Facebook [tells us to do it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart):

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And it used to work fine, it loads:

https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js

But I now changed my project to use webpack and that solution no longer works. Now when that code runs, it does add a new `<script>` tag in my page (just like before):

```
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
```

But if I check the network tab in the browser, instead of requesting:

https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js

it is requesting:

data:application/javascript;base64,RkI9e2dldExvZ2luU3RhdHVzOmZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7fSxhcGk6ZnVuY3Rpb24oKXt9LHVpOmZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7fSxFdmVudDp7c3Vic2NyaWJlOmZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7fX0sVUlTZXJ2ZXI6e30sWEZCTUw6e3BhcnNlOmZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7fX0saW5pdDpmdW5jdGlvbigpe30sX19ub1N1Y2hNZXRob2RfXzpmdW5jdGlvbigpe319Ow==

which is base64 for this code:

```
FB={getLoginStatus:function(){},api:function(){},ui:function(){},Event:{subscribe:function(){}},UIServer:{},XFBML:{parse:function(){}},init:function(){},__noSuchMethod__:function(){}};
```

This is obviously not what I wanted, my `fbAsyncInit` function is never called. I do not get how webpack is interfering with this, dynamically injecting script tags should not have anything to do with webpack. I do am using webpack dev server plugin though, maybe it is intercepting the request? Anyway adding webpack and started to using webpack dev server are the only things I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I thought that Webpack Dev Server was intercepting the request somehow, but in the end it was a browser extension (Ghostery) that was intercepting it. If you have the same problem try to disable extensions.